# Python TypeError: 'Generic' object is not subscriptable - How to Declare and Instantiate a Generic Base Class

Tags: python, generics, base-class, typing

I am trying to create an Abstract Generic Base class in python utilizing the new type annotation functionality in python 3 and the support for generics.

I have a base class and a derived class defined as such:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Iterator, List, Dict, Optional

_T = TypeVar('_T')

class FileReader(Generic(_T)):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    def __init__(self, filename: str, verbose: bool = False):
        pass

_X = TypeVar('_X')

class EmploymentHistoryFileReader(FileReader[_X]):
    def __init__(self, filename: str, verbose: bool = False):
        FileReader.__init__(filename=filename, verbose=verbose)
```

And when I try to instantiate an object of type EmploymentHistoryFileReader[EmploymentHistoryFileRow] I get:

```
File "/Users/simon.hughes/GitHub/analytics-py-careerpathing/careerpathing/data/employment_history_file_reader.py", line 38, in <module>
class EmploymentHistoryFileReader(FileReader[_X]):
TypeError: 'Generic' object is not subscriptable
```

I have tried a lot of different things, such as specifying the value for the generic parameter when declaring the sub class or when instantiating the subclass, and they all result in the same error message. The core library has many examples of generic types working correctly, so I am confused as to why I get these errors.

Comment: In addition to the brackets fix, you shouldn't be setting `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta`. It's triply ineffective, because 1) they changed the syntax for specifying a metaclass in Python 3, 2) you don't have any abstract methods anyway, and 3) your class will inherit the `typing.GenericMeta` metaclass from `Generic[_T]`.

Comment: I do have abstract methods, I omitted them for brevity as they weren't impacting the problem. I was wondering if I needed it though as I saw the Generic class was an ABC, so I'll remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
class FileReader(Generic(_T)):
```

should use brackets for `Generic[_T]`:

```
class FileReader(Generic[_T]):
```

`Generic` is generic, and like any other generic ABC, you specify its type parameters in brackets.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed that, I have been staring at that code for too long. Will mark as answer as soon as it lets me.